# enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource Configuration error

Tags: database, web-applications, enterprise-library

In my web application, after starting it I get a configuration error.
This started happening after adding an project from another solution to the current solution.

[ScreenShot of the error](http://i55.tinypic.com/2ykdnpx.png)

`Line 4:      <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings,    Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>`
`Line 5:      <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>`
`Line 6:      <section name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>`
`Line 7:      <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">`
`Line 8:        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">`

`Source File: D:\SnT Applications\NIP Portal\SnT.Nip-branch_PortalMessaging\SnT.Nip.Web\web.config    Line: 6`

And during the debug, when the database in called, it throws an exception that the .dll is missing, and an open file dialog pops up.

If anybody has encountered this problem, or has an solution to it, please help.

The current version of the Microsoft.Practices.EntityLibrary.Configuration is 5.0.414.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Enterprise Library 5 (which I'm assuming you are since you mention version 5.0.414.0) then you need to update your configuration file to reference that version of Enterprise Library.  Currently the configuration is referencing version 4.